# Handling the success and error response when they have different structure from each other

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am building an android app and the response for success and error comes in a different structure (it returns different objects) for both of them. How do you handle this using Kotlin, retrofit, and coroutines, since I have only dealt with the same structure responses How do you write the fun type on the API call, and how do you handle different responses in the viewModelScope and observe method. Below is an example of my response:
Success response:

```
{
 "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Error response:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "Invalid credentials",
            "type": "invalid-credentials"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your api you should have a method look like that and it returns a retrofit response :

```
@POST//or @GET or any http method you want
suspend fun userLogin(//Parameters) : Response<LoginResponse>
```

to perform a request you will write something like that :

```
val response = RetrofitInstance.api.userLogin(username, password)//this will return a response
//now we check if the response is successful or not
if(response.isSuccessful){//a response is successful when the response code is 2XX
    return response.body //respnse.body = LoginResponse
}

//if the response failed that means the response code is different than 2XX
//so the response body will be null and response.errorBody will contain the errorResponse you specified
val gson = Gson()
val type = object : TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.type //ErrorResponse is the data class that matches the error response
val errorResponse = gson.fromJson<ErrorResponse>(response.errorBody()!!.charStream(), type) // errorResponse is an instance of ErrorResponse that will contain details about the error

//either throw an exception or return null 
throw Exception(errorResponse.error)
```

Comment: What about SuccessResponse?

Comment: can you show the code of your request?

Comment: Since I showed the response of the login, I'm also showing the request of the login. This is the loginRequest data class:
data class Request (
val username: String,
val password: String
)

Comment: @FrensisXh i want to see the code of the request where you make the api call with retrofit

Comment: I hope this is what you mean: 
suspend fun userLogin(username: String, password: String): LoginResponse {
        return RetrofitInstance.api.userLogin(username, password)
    } 
even though I'm not sure how should the type of the function be since I get two different responses, can I add success and error in the same data class?

Comment: @FrensisXh i edited the answer hope it will help you

Comment: okay, I get it, I will implement it and then let you know if it works or not.

Comment: @FrensisXh ok if you find any troubles let me know

Comment: Actually, I am using Moshi, how different will the code above be since I'm not using Gson but Moshi?